# Run remote python code via ssh with uninstalled modules

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I wish to connect to a Linux machine by ssh (from my code) and run some code that is using python libraries that are not installed on the remote machine, what would be the best way to do so?

using a call like this:

```
cat main.py | ssh user@server python -
```

will run main.py on the server, but wont help me with the dependencies, is there a way to somehow 'compile' the relevant libraries and have them sent over just for the running my code?

I wish to avoid installing the libraries on the remote machine if possible

Comment: The best way to do it is to have a proper environment on the remote machine.

Comment: So where would you store these libraries? they need to be accessible for the Python environment to use them. One approach that may fit your scenario (not sure as you provide too little information) would be to have the libraries on a shared folder (NFS, Samba, ...) and add those to the Python path in your remote environment.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by saying 'a proper environment', i have a server that is running some vm's on it and i want to run a code that connects to them and tests for relevant connectives such as database connectivity, ping between some of them etc... i want to run it from one place

Comment: If what you want is to send a single file and run it instead of sending a bunch of files you could check for compilers like cython and nuitka, or if you don't mind switching languages, go and rust can generate single file executables and are very easy to learn for people with Python knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/):

```
pip install virtualenv
```

then use

```
virtualenv venv
```

to create a seperated python environment in current path(in folder `venv`).

Instead of installing multiple packages in default python path, virtualenv needs only one package installed.